# How to automatically loop a background actor object in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, scroll, 2d, actor, stage

I would like to make a 2D Side-scroller game, where the game world/game stage is moving to the left, i.e. The background is transitioning to the left like Flappy Bird. Any ideas how I am able to automatically loop a background Actor object which has the same width and height as the Stage's Orthographic camera?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is really simple. All you need to do is use the moveBy(x, y) method on the Actor instance.

```
float xMovingDelta = 10;
float yMovingDelta = 10;
actor.moveBy(xMovingDelta, yMovingDelta);
// Make sure you call the moveBy() method in a loop eg. the render() method.
```

Here is an example from my past game: It uses a Table instance but they both have the moveBy() method.

```
private void mMenuToDiffMenuAnimation() { // I call this method from the render() meth.
    if(difficultyTable.getX() > (540 - 64)){
        menuTable.moveBy(-30, 0);
        difficultyTable.moveBy(-30, 0);
    }else {
        fromMMToDiffMenu = false; 
       /* When the table's xPos is greater than 540 -64 stop the animation.*/
    }

}
```

Comment: this solution does not produce a continuous loop , but it shifts only once

Comment: @Mr.Developer - Thats why i added a comment that the moveBy() method needs to be called in a loop.